# compilation error when using maven apklib

Tags: android, maven, compiler-errors, apklib

I create a library project and `packing` as `apklib`. In application I added depedency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

I use lib in my app project like: `com.ati.common_lib.Test.demo();` and use `mvn clean install`. It worked! But if I use `import com.ati.common_lib;` and `Test.demo();` and `mvn clean build` it throw the error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project soci-news: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Data/Work/workspace/soci-parent/soci-news/src/main/java/com/ati/soci_news/HelloAndroidActivity.java:[9,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class common_lib
[ERROR] location: package com.ati
[ERROR] /Data/Work/workspace/soci-parent/soci-news/src/main/java/com/ati/soci_news/HelloAndroidActivity.java:[23,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : variable Test
[ERROR] location: class com.ati.soci_news.HelloAndroidActivity
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :soci-news
```

I am using maven 3.0.5, eclipse "kepler version" with m2e-android. Library and app I created by m2e-android. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

My parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
    <artifactId>soci-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Soci project parent</name>

    <modules>
        <module>common-lib</module>
        <module>soci-news</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <sdk>
                            <platform>8</platform>
                        </sdk>
                        <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

My library pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
        <artifactId>soci-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apklib</packaging>
    <name>common lib for ati android application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version> 2.2.1
        </platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.6.1</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My app's pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
        <artifactId>soci-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
    <artifactId>soci-news</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>soci-news</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ati</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can we see all your POMs?

Comment: Your HelloAndroidActivity was not found. Make sure that if you use that then you can use that.

Comment: @LajosArpad: I sure that my HelloAndroidActivity class appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is broken.

`com.ati.common-lib` is the package, but you really want to import the contents of that package, `com.ati.common-lib.*` for everything and `com.ati.common-lib.Test` for just the Test class.

Comment: I try to use mvn clean package and mvn clean install in each maven project (lib project, app project and parent project ), but no luck. The compilation error when I use in parent project or app project. I really do not understand your mind, so I wonder this error can be fixed or not?

Comment: Can you try import com.ati.common_lib.*; or import com.ati.common_lib.Test;

Comment: OK!!! It's worked, very strange :)). Thank you very much. If you don't mind, may I ask you another question: In this picture http://imgur.com/5lvgPkq is my eclipse file editor. Eclipse doesnot recognize the R file, Test class...etc, and offcourse it does not show me code suggestion as I usally use normal android project with out maven. Do you know why? and how to fixed it? Sorry for this childlike question, because I am a newbie of maven. Many thank.

Comment: I think you should update your answer to import com.ati.common_lib.*; for later people understand.